# Custom query with go-pg into []String slice

Tags: postgresql, go, orm

I'm using https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg a bunch of other places in the code so I'm hoping I don't have to switch to another client.

I can't get the ORM to write this query (below) correctly, so I just want to pass it thru as a custom string.  But I can't figure out how to get the results into my []string slice.

```golang
tokens := []string{}

qry := `SELECT p.token
      FROM pntokens p
      join
      (VALUES ('123'), ('456'), ('789')) AS t (userid)
    on p.userid = t.userid ;`
```

I've tried:

```golang
err := db.Model(&Pntoken{}, qry).Select(&tokens)
err := db.Query([]string{}, qry, nil).Select(&tokens)
_, err := db.Exec(qry)

res, err := db.Model((*Pntoken)(nil)).Exec(qry)
```

But cannot get the tool out of my way enough to just get some simple results into my slice.

All tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use like this for lib https://github.com/go-pg/pg:

```
tokens := []string
    qry := `SELECT p.token FROM pntokens p
            join (VALUES ('123'), ('456'), ('789')) AS t (userid)
            on p.userid = t.userid ;`
    
    _, err := pc.DB.Query(&tokens,"qry",nil)
    if err != nil {
            return tokens, err
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).